# Error when connecting to MySQL database using mysql.connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using mysql.connector:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="user",
  password="password",
  database="database"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table") 


myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

print(myresult)
```

I get this error message:

errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on'localhost:3306'(10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

Does this mean that there something wrong with the database credentials?

Comment: can you connect with the mysql client or workbench

Comment: I needed to replace "localhost" by the IP address, it works now